# Vuetify Slide-Group Automatic Cycle

Tags: nuxt.js, slider, vuetify.js

There are several questions asked on this topic but not quiet what I need. Would it be possible to add a automatic cycle event to a Vuetify slide-group that cycles right every say 3 seconds or so, and if possible reset after the last image is reached?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups/#pseudo-carousel

Could an event be set to the right click arrow that automatically presses the button every three seconds and if possible what would this look like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.